# не получается установить R

Tags: r

Нужно установить R. убунту 18.04. Пробовала:

1. https://cran.r-project.org/ инструкции отсюда.
   Копирую deb https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu xenial-cran40/ в /etc/apt/sources.list, нажимаю закрыть, пишет
   E:The repository 'http://cran.rstudio.com/bin/linux/ubuntu bionic/ Release' does not have
   Перебрала все 4 варианта, которые предлагается добавлять в /etc/apt/sources.list, нет разницы
2. инструкции, подобные этой https://www.tutorialspoint.com/how-to-install-and-configure-r-on-ubuntu-16-04
   спотыкается на этом:
   Ошб:14 http://cran.rstudio.com/bin/linux/ubuntu bionic/ Release
   404  Not Found [IP: 13.33.243.35 80]
   E: Репозиторий «http://cran.rstudio.com/bin/linux/ubuntu bionic/ Release» не содержит файла Release.
   N: Обновление из этого репозитория нельзя выполнить безопасным способом, поэтому по умолчанию он отключён.
   N: Информацию о создании репозитория и настройках пользователя смотрите в справочной странице apt-secure(8).
3. отсюда https://www.r-bloggers.com/2016/04/how-to-install-r-on-linux-ubuntu-16-04-xenial-xerus/
   sudo apt-get install r-base r-base-dev
   Итог:
   Следующие пакеты имеют неудовлетворённые зависимости:
   r-base : Зависит: r-base-core (>= 4.0.3-1.2004.0) но он не будет установлен
   Зависит: r-recommended (= 4.0.3-1.2004.0) но он не будет установлен
   Рекомендует: r-base-html но он не будет установлен
   r-base-dev : Зависит: r-base-core (>= 4.0.3-1.2004.0) но он не будет установлен
   E: Невозможно исправить ошибки: у вас зафиксированы сломанные пакеты.
4. скачала R 4.0.3.
   ./configure
   configure: error: PCRE2 library and headers are required, or use --with-pcre1 and PCRE >= 8.32 with UTF-8 support
   --with-pcre1 не помогает

Нужны максимально простые советы на уровне "скопируйте это и это", для совсем новичка.

Comment: Много раз действовал по этому мануалу https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-r-on-ubuntu-18-04 в начале мануала можно выбрать ОС в соответствии с которой будут даны инструкции в мануале.

Comment: kandellak, пробовала. на этой стадии sudo add-apt-repository 'deb https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu bionic-cran40/' выдает ошибку (как в п. 2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

устанавливайте пакеты из официального репозитория вашего дистрибутива:

```
$ sudo apt-get install r-base
```

пакет `r-base` [присутствует в репозиториях всех актуальных версий](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=r-base&searchon=names&suite=all&section=all) вашего дистрибутива.

> у вас зафиксированы сломанные пакеты

порядок надо в системе наводить. к пакету `r-base` это явно не имеет никакого отношения. и с уверенностью можно сказать, что вызвана ошибка тем бардаком, который вы попытались развести в системе. уберите всё, что вы наисправляли в `/etc/apt/sources*`, обновите список пакетов и попробуйте поставить `r-base`.

Comment: Благодарю! Всё заработало.

Comment: А можете объяснить, что значит "наводить порядок в системе", как "обновить список пакетов" и как "убрать все, что наисправляли в /etc/apt/sources*"?

Comment: @ГлебДильман, если у вас появился новый вопрос, задайте его, пожалуйста, с помощью кнопки «[задать вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask)» в правом верхнем углу страницы.